# Target-specific values in interface builder

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I have two targets and I want to use one launch screen storyboard for them but I need to use different constraint multipliers for my logo image in those targets. Since it's a launch screen, I cannot change the multiplier value programmatically.

Is there a way to use target-specific values for storyboard in Interface builder?

Comment: It is probably simpler to duplicate the storyboard and add the appropriate storyboard to each target

Comment: @Paulw11 That's true. I'm just wondering if it is possible at all